# Nginx proxy to variable URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'd like to create a reverse proxy that results in the following:

```
/proxy/?url=http://takemehere.com/....
```

reverse proxy to

```
http://takemehere.com/....
```

I tried this to no avail:

```
location ~ /proxy/?url=(.*) {
    proxy_pass $1
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!